# Issue with Jira Rest Api

Tags: java, jira

Problem with using Jira rest API.
I want to hit the jira and has to get the issues,scenarios from jira through java standalone.

My company using Jira with SAML and SSO. If I directly pass jira url https://jira.mycompany.com and with the basic credentials to the jira rest api it throws "peer not authenticated" exception.Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated. when I mouse hover on the JIRA link in my company website it shows the following url.

https://mycompany.com/M2/saml20/logininitial?RequestBinding=HTTPPost&PartnerId=https://jira.mycompany.com/plugins/servlet/samlsso&NameIdFormat=email.

Can some one help me on this how to use jira rest api for this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the certificate. You need to either provide key to login/ access url in your code.

I am not sure about java but i have written python script to bypass the certificate verification. Below is the code snipped

```
import urllib2, base64
import requests
import ssl
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint
import getpass

UserName = raw_input("Ener UserName: ")

pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')

request = urllib2.Request("https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/project")

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (UserName, pswd)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string) 
gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request, context=gcontext)

JsonGroupdata = result.read()
jsonToPython = json.loads(JsonGroupdata)
```